# AngularJS $resource - POST with id param

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an angularJS $resource:

```
$resource("http://localhost:3000/:id",{
   id: '@id'
},
{
   get: {
      method:'GET',
      isArray: false
   },
   foo: {
      method:'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/:id/foo',
      isArray: false
   }
});
```

Now if I call:

```
User.foo({id:'123', anotherParam: 'bar'});
```

This results in the URL 'http://localhost:3000/foo' being called and passing the id and anotherParam parameters as POST fields.

I actually want it to call 'http://localhost:3000/123/foo' and only pass the anotherParam parameter as a POST field.

How do I get the id parameter to behave correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])

You need to do:

```
User.foo({id:'123', anotherParam: 'bar'}, <post data object>);
```

When you call the function with a single argument. It assumes that the optional argument is not there and sends it as the postData.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me (`AngularJS v1.4.8`). 
Have to manually set content type and transform to form data.

Sample:

```
var DirectoryApi = $resource('api/directories', null, {
    move: {
        url: 'api/directories/:name/_move',
        params: {"name" : "@name"},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
        transformRequest: function (param) {
            return $.param(param);
        },
        method: 'POST'
    },
});
```

And usage:

```
function moveDirectory(name, parent, after) {
    return DirectoryApi.move({name: name}, {parent: parent, after: after});
}
```